# Determine if the improper integral converges $\sin(1/x)$

Tags: calculus

I tried comparing it with $\sin(x)$ but $\sin(1/x)$ is $\geq$ than $\sin(x)$ and the integer of $\sin(x)$ converges so that doesn't help me

$$\int_0^{1} \sin (\frac{1}x) dx$$

Comment: $\sin\leq1$ seems to be enough here.

Comment: If you only need to determine whether the integral exists, and not necessarily what it might evaluate to, then you need to go into partitions of the interval $[0,1]$ and upper and lower sums.

Answer (score 3):

It is not an improper integral. $\sin(1/x)$ is continuous and bounded on $(0,1]$, so it is integrable.

Comment: Now I'm curious: is there an analytic way to compute it?

Answer (score 1):

The function $x\mapsto \sin(1/x)$ is bounded, and like any bounded function, its integral over a bounded set converges (assuming the integral makes sense, but here your function is continuous on $]0,1]$, so both Lebesgue or Riemann's framework would agree here that your function is integrable).